# Find the locus of a point which moves so that the tangents from it to a circle are at right angles.

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, locus

Find the locus of a point which moves so that the tangents from it to a circle are at right angles.

My Attempt :
Let $P(x_1,y_1)$ be any moving point and $x^2 + y^2=a^2$ be the equation of the circle. Then, 
Centre of the circle is $(0,0)$ and its radius is $a$
Now, equation of tangent is $xx_1+yy_1=a^2$

How do I complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need analytic geometry to solve this problem: the following picture shows that the center of the circle, the two tangent points and point $P$ are the vertices of a square.

[image: The locus searched]

Comment: Zar.Very nice !

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Consider one static position for that point $P$, then the distance from the center of the given circle is

- $d=\sqrt{a^2+a^2}=a\sqrt 2$

Now consider $P$ moving and note that distance $d$ can't varies in order to mantain the tangents orthogonal.

Comment: what formula did you use for distance?  Please elaborate

Comment: @blue_eyed_...consider a circle with radius "$a$" and two orthogonal tangents, then the intersction point P is the vertex of a square with side "$a$", then $OP=a\sqrt 2$ by Pythagoras.

Comment: could you please provide me a figure for this?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... refer to https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=obh4RffT&id=D977FDB182D6D10B27068C579DC6E5B1F2CB7120&thid=OIP.obh4RffTthBjJcO1bgZ6-AHaGd&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fgogeometry.com%2fschool-college%2f2%2fp1156-square-circle-tangent-metric-relation.gif&exph=600&expw=687&q=circle+tangents+square&simid=608052957781428122&selectedIndex=2&ajaxhist=0

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q,R$ be the points of tangency with the circle, $O$ the circle centre.

Note : $OQPR$ is a square, side length $= r$, $r$ is radius of the circle.

The locus of $P$ is a circle centred at $O$ with radius $R$:

$R =\sqrt{r^2+r^2} =√2r$$